# How can I determine the register bit widths correctly?

Tags: verilog, xilinx

This is the simple code I wrote.From 'outt' I get 122116. But if I change 'outt' width to be 33 bits ([32:0]) then code seems to work and give the correct answer -140028. What is the reason for this behaviour??

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module valu_parser(clk,outt);

input clk;
reg signed [31:0] r_1;
reg signed [31:0] r_2;
output reg signed [31:0] outt;

initial begin
    r_1 = -47938;
    r_2 = -150096;
end

always @ (posedge clk) begin
    outt <= ((r_1 + r_2)* 11585 + 8192)>>>14;
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

You are performing an operation that needs at least 33 bits (the temporary result before the right shift uses 33 bits) and theoretically it could need 32+"the size of the multiplicand constant" assuming that r_1 and r_2 are not constants.

If you think of the hardware your code will generate, these bits needs to be stored somewhere temporarily to allow the hardware to first perform multiplication, then addition followed by the right shift.

This will do the trick, but will also generate more registers than you wanted initially. If you are using this module to generate a constant, I would recommend hard-coding the constant.

```
module valu_parser(clk,outt);

input clk;
reg signed [31:0] r_1;
reg signed [31:0] r_2;
reg signed [32:0] temp;
output reg signed [31:0] outt;

initial begin
    r_1 = -47938;
    r_2 = -150096;
end

always @ (posedge clk) begin
    temp <= ((r_1 + r_2)* 11585 + 8192);
end

assign outt = temp>>>14;

endmodule
```

The concept can be seen here: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3BXy.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

In an expression Verilog needs to decide how many bits to use in the calculation.

The `+` and `*` operators result in what are called *context-determined expressions*. With the expression `F = A + B;` the number of bits used is the maximum of `F`, `A`, and `B`. This usually works fine, because normally you would ensure that `F` was wide enough to store the result of adding `A` and `B`. Likewise with the expression `F = A * B;` would usually work fine, because normally you would ensure that `F` was wide enough to store the result of multiplying `A` and `B`.

However, by adding the shift right operator you have been able to make the variable being assigned narrower than the number of bits actually needed to calculate the expression on the left of the shift operator. The number of bits Verilog uses in the calculation is the maximum of the width of `outt`, `r_1`, `r_2`, `11585` and `8192`. All of these are 32 bits wide (including `11585` and `8192`), so 32 bits are used in the calculation. As you have discovered, 32 bits is not enough, but, with the values you have chosen, 33 bits is. With other values, 33 bits wouldn't be enough either. For a completely flexible solution, you should be using 66 bits (32 + 32 + 1 + 1) - 32 bits + 32 bits for the multiplication plus 1 more bit for each addition.

The solution to your problem is to make `r_1` and/or `r_2` wider or to use an intermediate value (as suggested by Hida's answer here).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! It clears that out! :)

Answer (score -1):

When you multiply -198034 (r1+r1) on 11585 you have in result highest bit is 0 (outt[31]), then if you have 32bit signed value its start be positive and in answer you have positive result. And when you change it for 33bit your highest bit is 1 (outt[32]) and result is negative value and you have correct answer.